# Is it possible to install Kali Linux on a windows tablet?

Tags: kali-linux

I have just purchased a windows tablet... http://www.ebuyer.com/664723-linx-7-windows-8-tablet-pc-linx7

I was wondering if it would be possible to dual boot it with a 32 bit version of Kali linux.

I want to learn how to be a pentester and I was informed that Kali Linux is the tool for this job.

If it is possible, could anyone leave any tips on how to do this.

I really appreciate the help.

Comment: A quick google search can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Linx 7 is a Bay Trail system with 32 bit UEFI.  That makes it a bit awkward to boot as most Linux distros are set up for 64 bit UEFI (which the Surface Pro 3 has, it's really an i5 laptop in tablet form, not a tablet CPU like the Bay Trail).

So you need a Linux image that supports booting from 32 bit UEFI.  Distros like Ubuntu support that, but I can't see any mention that Kali does.  The 32 bit Kali boot images are probably set up to boot with BIOS only.

What you might do is install Debian (there appears to be an [unofficial development CD image](http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/efi-development/jessie-upload3/) ) and then [add the Kali repositories and install its packages](https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?18825-kali-jessie-cinnamon1-9-git).  It won't be as polished as installing from scratch (so perhaps not for an absolute beginner), but I think it's the only way to make things work currently.

Comment: I Forgot I had even posted this here. I have recently managed to install Kali on the tablet. Same method as you mentioned. I had watched hours of youtube videos to get this to work. I ended up taking the 32 Bit UEFI .Efi file from Ubuntu and using it for kali. This worked but I hit a brick wall as it booted to GNU Linux command line. From this I had to use certain commands to load the install image. I will upload the codes if anyone requests them. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Referring to the following sources:
http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-install-linux-on-surface-pro-3/

http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/66948-uefi-kali-linux-live-usb-on-surface-pro

**Yes, it is.**

*Make sure to keep the recovery partition to not mess things up*

The following approach is from the topmost source, describing how to install Debian on a Surface Pro 3, but the guid should hold true for the newer Surface Pro and Kali Linux.

You will need the following

Before you proceed, it is necessary to obtain the following devices:

- USB hub
- USB mouse
- USB keyboard
- Unfortunately, Debian fails to detect the integrated WiFi adapter of
  Surface Pro 3, so we need to use some USB Ethernet adapter or USB
  tethering from a smartphone. [Can't verify this is true for the
  newest Surface and Kali Linux]

**Save your recovery partition to a USB flash drive**

Besides the system and data partitions, Surface Pro 3 has a 5 GB recovery partition.

**Shrink the C: drive**

**Disable hibernation**

Power off your Surface Pro 3. Now press and hold the "+" volume button and power it on. It will boot to UEFI settings, where you should disable the Secure Boot feature. With Secure Boot disabled, it is possible to boot and install another OS. Shutdown Surface Pro 3 again.

**Install Kali Linux as usual.**

Answer (score -1):

I have a notebook with intel atom processor.
I  installed kali linux 32bit beside win7.
when i boot kali, the notebook will hibernate .
this happened after every 30 sec. 
what do i do ?

Comment: This does not answer the author's question.  You should edit this answer and provide specific and detailed steps on how the author solves their problem.

Comment: Or, if you have your own question that is different from this one, please ask your own question so that we can help you.

Answer (score -1):

Kali linux supports live OS, i would mount or burn the kali iso to a flash drive using rufus usb tool and then just boot kali from the flash drive leaving windows partition and all intact. I actually prefer PE (preinstall environment) and live OS for pen testing because all running in flasg gets dumped once shut down and leaves less of a footprint. If you want to save files while booting from live flash you will need to set up a specific partition to mount from the usb to store files but if you are wanting to save files when you shut down then your best bet might be to run it in virtual machine. If you use oracle free virtualbox you can set the network adapter in bridge mode or if you are really doing penetration testing i assume you would have an alpha wireless card that supports mon mode and being usb you can just mount the usb wireless and disable the NIC. Another benefit of booting kali from virtualbox is that you can import the kali virtual machine into GNS3 (a virtual network topography hypervisor) and simulate entire networks with switches routers and firewalls, you could also have a server virtual machine and connect both virtual machines to a virtual switcg and or router like a router on a stick situation and use that to learn how to use metasploit and other hacker tools on your own mini virtual network lab. If you are curious about doing that ive written a step by step guide on setting this up and all tools are free. It is an absolute must for anyone learning to become a pen tester. (I run a pci compliance and network security company and trust me, these tools will bump your learning up by a lot) email me at frostbittentongue@gmail.com.  i know this thread is old but im more than happy to assist anyone looking to expand their network security knowledge.